# Multiply jquery selectors with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery allows multiply selectors like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#popfrom, #poptill', function()
```

But my selectors come out of a variable like this:

```
$(document).on('change', adddatedropper, function()
```

Can someone please tell me how to add a second selector out of a variable? Do I need to make a single string out of both variables or is there another way?

Comment: The function (the `.on()` function) expects a single string, so you'll have to somehow combine your separate parts yourself somehow, depending on your needs.

Comment: Please share an example of what the value of `adddatedropper` might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to use string concatenation for the second selector

```
$(document).on('change', '#popfrom, #'+ adddatedropper, function()
```

Or you can use add for add two elements

```
$(adddatedropper).add(addtimedropper).
```

```js
var adddatedropper ="#div1";
var addtimedropper ="#div2";
var both = adddatedropper +' , ' + addtimedropper;

$(document).on("click",both,function() {
    alert("click bound to document listening");
});


$(adddatedropper).add(addtimedropper).on('click', function() {
  alert("click bound to document listening");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='div1'> div 1</div>
<div  id='div2'>div 2</div>
```

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful!!!

Comment: I did now: $(document).on('change', ''+ adddatedropper +', '+ addtimedropper +'', function() - but only the first variable gets respected. Am I doing something wrong here? The variables have the # in them

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer ok checking

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer i have updated my code please check.

Comment: Mohammad, I know what my problem is now. I have a "timedropper" on my "input". When the timedropper is activated no "change"-event gets fired. Even when the value changes. Do you have an idea what that could be?

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer you can try this
$('#timedropper"').on('touchend mouseup', function() {
    console.log('timedropper closed');
})

Answer (score 1):

## Multiple jQuery Selectors as a Variable

Assuming that each of your variables are valid jQuery/CSS selectors you could declare an array of those variables and then use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

```
 var v123 = [v1, v2, v3].join(', ');
 $(document).on('change', v123, callback);
```

With the exception being key events, delegating to `document` seems redundant and verbose. **Demo 2** delegates the `change` event directly to the selectors:

```
 var v123 = [v1, v2, v3].join(', ');
 $(v123).on('change', callback);
```

Of course the results are identical to **Demo 1**, it's less verbose and easier on the eyes IMO.

---

### Demo 1

#### `$(document).on('change', RCS, viewData);`

```js
var R = ':radio';
var C = ':checkbox';
var S = 'select';
var RCS = [R, C, S].join(', ');

$(document).on('change', RCS, viewData);

function viewData(e) {
  $('output').val($(this).val());
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: fit-content;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

output {
  display: block;
  min-width: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type='radio' name='rad' value='1'>1
  <input type='radio' name='rad' value='3'>3
  <input type='radio' name='rad' value='5'>5
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2'>2
  <input type='checkbox' value='4'>4
  <input type='checkbox' value='6'>6
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <output></output>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Demo 2

#### `$(RCS).on('change', viewData);`

```js
var R = ':radio';
var C = ':checkbox';
var S = 'select';
var RCS = [R, C, S].join(', ');

$(RCS).on('change', viewData);

function viewData(e) {
  $('output').val($(this).val());
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: fit-content;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

output {
  display: block;
  min-width: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type='radio' name='rad' value='1'>1
  <input type='radio' name='rad' value='3'>3
  <input type='radio' name='rad' value='5'>5
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2'>2
  <input type='checkbox' value='4'>4
  <input type='checkbox' value='6'>6
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <output></output>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$(document).on('change', '#'+$(adddatedropper).attr('id')+', #'+ $(addtimedropper).attr('id'), function()
```